# Flutter : Update text using Valuenotifier

Tags: flutter, widget

I am using `valuenotifier` to update a text as an **alternative to** having a **stateful widget** and calling setstate. I was able to get the selected value from the `dropdownFormField`but could not display it.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=62d831a1b6ff472e080d5b18f9bae2ef&null_safety=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add this to the `onChanged` method:

```
_text.value = value.toString();
```

This will update the value of your `ValueNotifier` and the `ValueListenableBuilder` will catch it and rebuild.